# What is the fastest way to sort numbers lexicographically?

Tags: computational-complexity, multiset

I have $N$ sequences of numbers. None of them is longer than $10^6$. I want to sort those sequences lexicographically. For example, given sequences {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 5, 7}, {2}, I want to have them sorted in this way - {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {2}, {2, 5, 7}. What is the fastest way to do this? Using quicksort and just comparing them in a normal way I can get $O(N∗K∗logN)$ but this is very slow.

Comment: What is $K$ in your big O?

Comment: It is the length of the longest sequence. In example above K = 3, because length of the longest sequence is 3.

Comment: Since you are assuming that $K\leq 10^6$, you don't need to include it in the big O.

Comment: Does it happen often that long initial sequences of two of your sequences are equal?

Comment: Are all the integers quite small?  If so, a version of radix sort for mixed-length strings will take time proportional to the total length of the strings.

Comment: @Brendan: And even if they aren't, you could still effect a radix sort by using a comparison-based sorting routine on each digit rather than a bucket sort.

Comment: This looks like it is from a programming competition.

Comment: @DouglasZare It seems far too basic for that to be the case.

Comment: @Adam P. Goucher: It does look like it might be too easy, but there are a lot of programming competitions which start with trivial problems and then include tougher questions. In addition, there are usually tests that are of a size so that poor algorithms will time out, and it sounds like that happened. This user has posted other harder problems with the same style. It could be homework instead, though.

Comment: It is not from a programming competition. I am solving problems from SPOJ, UVA, CodeForces etc. and recently I've been doing task that required fast algorithm for comparing sequences lexicographically. Solution with quicksort was fast enough, because data wasn't big, but I wondered if there exist algorithm that could do it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be your set of sequences.

We construct increasingly refined partitions of $S$, where each class in the partition is associated to a node of a tree. Initially, the partition consists of one class (the entirety of $S$), and the tree consists of one node (the root). In your example, the initial state would look like this:

[image: Initial state]

If there is a node $N$ in layer $\ell$ (where the root node is layer $0$) with more than one sequence associated to it, we create child nodes for each distinct symbol $\sigma$ occurring in the $(\ell + 1)$th position of any of the sequences, and move the sequences accordingly:

[image: State after first operation]

We repeat again for each of the other nodes, since they both have more than one associated sequence. Since the sequence $(2)$ does not have a second element, we leave it where it is. After both of these operations, the tree looks like this:

[image: State after second and third operations]

There is only one node remaining with more than one associated sequence. It's in the second layer, so we compare the third elements of the sequences. The tree then becomes this, at which point we terminate since all nodes have at most one associated sequence:

[image: Final state of tree]

Now we can just do a *preorder traversal* of this tree, which takes time linear in the tree size.

Note that in the worst-case scenario this algorithm takes at linear time in the input size, $O(KN)$. Moreover, it is often considerably faster ($\Theta(N \log N)$ for random sequences) since it does not have to read the entire input -- in the example given, it never needs to read the symbol $7$ in the sequence $(2, 5, 7)$.

Indeed, I claim optimality of this algorithm, since it reads the minimum number of symbols required to distinguish between all of the sequences, and the time complexity is proportional to that quantity.

Comment: This is how radix sorts for mixed length strings.  The time $O(KN)$ assumes you can sort a set of integers in linear time, which is true if only a constant number of integers can occur but isn't true in general.  If the sets all have a single element but they can be arbitrary integers, you need $O(N\log N)$.

Comment: Relevant keyword: "trie". It's worth noting that this is not only good for sorting them, but for *storing* them as well, depending on the actual data and data structures.